# React Native how to use Braintree PayPal Value

Tags: react-native, paypal, braintree

I use react-native to develop an app, and I need to connect to braintree (paypal value). The official provides 3 kinds of sdk, js, android, and ios. I try to connect to the native android library, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.After calling the native method in ReactNative, only "react-native-test" is output (No error is reported, and there is no change on the interface. It seems that it should jump to PayPal authorization to be normal). I'm not sure if it's my problem . I also tried to use js library in react-native, but after importing a certain method, my program doesn't start. Or can I only do it in webView? Has anyone connected with PayPal value? Can you give me some advice? Thanks.

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/vault/android/v4) I refer to.

Below is my android code：

```java
public class BraintreeValueModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements PayPalListener {
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private Callback successCallback;
    private Callback errorCallback;
    private BraintreeClient braintreeClient;
    private PayPalClient payPalClient;

    public BraintreeValueModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "BraintreeValueModule";
    }
    @ReactMethod
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("react-native-test");
        braintreeClient = new BraintreeClient(reactContext.getApplicationContext(), "sandbox_ykbznr4s_ctmssyj6wz2qcj2g");
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) getCurrentActivity();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new MyRunnable(activity,braintreeClient));
        //The following writing method will report an error: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
        //if(activity != null){
        //    payPalClient = new PayPalClient(activity, braintreeClient);
        //    payPalClient.setListener(this);
        //}
    }



    @Override
    public void onPayPalSuccess(@NonNull PayPalAccountNonce payPalAccountNonce) {
        successCallback.invoke(payPalAccountNonce.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPayPalFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
        if (error instanceof UserCanceledException) {
            // user canceled
            errorCallback.invoke("use canceled");
        } else {
            // handle error
            errorCallback.invoke("error");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable, PayPalListener {
    private BraintreeClient braintreeClient;
    private PayPalClient payPalClient;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    MyRunnable(FragmentActivity activity,BraintreeClient braintreeClient){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.braintreeClient = braintreeClient;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(activity != null){
            payPalClient = new PayPalClient(activity, braintreeClient);
            payPalClient.setListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPayPalSuccess(@NonNull PayPalAccountNonce payPalAccountNonce) {
        System.out.println(payPalAccountNonce.getString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPayPalFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
        if (error instanceof UserCanceledException) {
            // user canceled
            System.out.println("use canceled");
        } else {
            // handle error
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might have missed out the following few lines:

```
PayPalVaultRequest request = new PayPalVaultRequest();
request.setBillingAgreementDescription("Your agreement description");
payPalClient.tokenizePayPalAccount(getCurrentActivity(), request);
```

However, I believe it might still not work as I had similar problem when I was trying to integrate the drop-in.
I'm afraid that you'll need to initialise your clients (in your case, BraintreeClient and PaypalClient) in the onCreate method of your MainActivity.
And then try to call a reference to the client (either by SharedPreference or static variable) in your module to launch the drop in.
Pretty sure it's similar issue to your case.
This only applies to the v4 library.

Read more on this thread:
https://github.com/braintree/braintree-android-drop-in/issues/374#issuecomment-1345929549